# Как создаются оболочки для смартфонов?

Tags: android, ос

Существуют различные оболочки на андройд для смартфонов. Например, Origin OS, Realme UI и т.д. Возможно ли создать свою оболочку для смартфона и если да, то где поискать материал на данную тему. Я понимаю, что они базируются на "чистом андройде", но каким образом для создаются оболочки?